# javascript alert not working when handling exception in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, exception, alert

I tried to handle duplicate exception, where if it catch the duplicate exception it should pop up some javascript alert with message

Below is the code I'm using :

```
 public function storeNeraca(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $neraca = new Neraca;
            $neraca->outlet = $request->outlet;
            $neraca->bulan = $request->bulan;
            $neraca->tahun = $request->tahun;
            $neraca->kode = $request->outlet.$request->bulan.$request->tahun;
            $neraca->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) { 
            if ($e->getCode() == 23000) {
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Data yang diminta sudah tersedia")';
                echo '</script>';
            }
        }
        
        
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

the result is, it doesn't create a new Neraca (because it's a duplicate), it also doesn't show error stack trace (it's a good thing), but it also doesn't show pop alert, which I hope it should show it, can anynone help where i get things wrong?

Comment: Which code returns `$e->getCode()` ?